# How to close excel correctly using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Here is the sub

```
Sub test()
With ThisWorkbook
.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 5
.Save
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the vbscript that starts the sub

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Book1.xlsm")
ObjExcel.Visible = True
ObjExcel.Run "Book1.xlsm!test"
ObjWB.Close False

Set ObjExcel = Nothing ' Should I use  ObjExcel.Quit instead ?
'if i use both I get the error
```

I get the following vbscript run - time error

[image]

Comment: If you comment out the line `Set ObjExcel = Nothing` does the error go away?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a line of code after `Set ObjExcel = Nothing`? Like a `ObjExcel.Quit` statement? Because your error suggests that you're trying to call a instance method for an object that's been dereferenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, since the code you posted apparently does *not* raise an error (at least according to the comments in your code), but most likely you used `ObjExcel.Quit` and `Set ObjExcel = Nothing` in the wrong order. If you set `ObjExcel` to `Nothing` before calling `ObjExcel.Quit` the variable doesn't contain an object with a `Quit` method anymore, thus raising the error you observed.

You must use `ObjExcel.Quit` if you want to terminate Excel. Without it the program will keep running even when the script terminates. However, you must call the method before setting the variable to `Nothing` (which is optional), so change this:

```
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

to either this:

```
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

or this:

```
ObjExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I don't also set the open workbook to Nothing, I end up with ~temp copy of my spreadsheet that causes it to be locked. It also leaves the Excel task running and viewable in Task Manager.
So, when done with the spreadsheet I use:

```
objExcel.application.quit
Set objFileName = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```